# "Vaishakehu" Extra Points over entire word? or some letters?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, mesorah-tradition, spelling-variants, biblical-criticism

Shalom! 
The famous Passuk on which Esav and Jaacov  ran, hug, kiss and cry.
The Word VAISHAKEHU has **points-dots over every leter**.

Siftei Chakhamim seems to have **VAISHAKEHU וישקהו** with 5 nekudot, except for the Shin.
Does anyone know the source? is it possible?

I can't found any textual variant on the Masoretic Points, nor any reference to this Siftei Chakhamim peirush!!

Minhat Shai, C.D.Ginsburg, Keniccott, M.M.Casher, other Masorah rabbis and academics... Even Leningrad has 6 dots! (The only mention of 5 dots is M.Breuer, Daat Mikra, from Bomberg 2nd Mikraot Gedolot, I checked it and it's right, but it seems more a print mistake...)

The Siftei Chakhamim peirush is meaningful and original, but it starts on explaining Rashi's words that really I don't see them, it's not reasonable. Also I didn't match any other Rashi's SupraCommentary that says a word. Siftei Chakhamim's Author Rabbi Shabetai Bas doesn't bring any makor-source for his peirush...

Does anyone can enlight this??
Thanks you very much!
Natan Waingortin

Texts Source:
https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.33.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.33.4.2&lang2=bi&w2=Siftei%20Chakhamim&lang3=en

**TORAH:**
וַיָּ֨רָץ עֵשָׂ֤ו לִקְרָאתוֹ֙ וַֽיְחַבְּקֵ֔הוּ וַיִּפֹּ֥ל עַל־צַוָּארָ֖ו **וַׄיִּׄשָּׁׄקֵ֑ׄהׄוּׄ** וַיִּבְכּֽוּ

**RASHI:**

**וישקהו**. נָקוּד עָלָיו; וְיֵשׁ חוֹלְקִין בַּדָּבָר הַזֶּה בַּבָּרַיְתָא דְּסִפְרֵי, יֵשׁ שֶׁדָּרְשׁוּ נְקֻדָּה זוֹ שֶׁלֹּא נְשָׁקוֹ בְּכָל לִבּוֹ, אָמַר רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן יוֹחַאי, הֲלָכָה הִיא בְּיָדוּעַ שֶׁעֵשָׂו שׂוֹנֵא לְיַעֲקֹב, אֶלָּא שֶׁנִּכְמְרוּ רַחֲמָיו בְּאוֹתָהּ שָׁעָה וּנְשָׁקוֹ בְּכָל לִבּוֹ (ספרי במדבר):
וישקהו

AND HE KISSED HIM — Dots are placed above the letters of this word, and a difference of opinion is expressed in the Baraitha of Sifré (בהעלותך) as to what these dots are intended to suggest: ...etc. (Sifrei Bamidbar 69.2)

**SIFTEI CHAKHAMIM:**

יש שדרשו נקודה זו לומר שלא נשקו בכל לבו. ר"ל **מלת וישקהו נקוד לבד השי"ן שבו אינה נקודה** והוי כאילו כתיב ויק"הו לשון הקהה את שיניו (הגדה של פסח) שהיה בדעתו לנשכו:

There are those who explained these dots as saying that he did not kiss him wholeheartedly. **Meaning: וישקהו has dots on all letters except the ש.** Thus it is as if it is written ויקהו, as in הקהה את שיניו (blunt his teeth — Pesach Haggadah). This is because he intended to bite him.

**MINJAT SHAI:**

וישקהו. **נקוד שש נקודות נקודה על כל אות**. ב"ר, ושיר השירים רבה, על צוארך כמגדל השן. וספר הזוהר, וספרים אחרים, שכתבתי בפ' לך לך על ביני וביניך, ובפרקי ר' אליעזר, אל תקרי וישקהו אלא וישכהו וכו'. ועיין עוד בזוהר פ' משפטים דף קכ"ד:

Comment: Can you please formulate a clear question here, not a problem.

Comment: @natan the simple understanding of Rashi is to say that the entire word is in question, and therefore there are points over each letter.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You found a source that has only 5 dots. That's the one Siftei Chachanim saw. And indeed it's probably just a printing mistake. Everything for an answer is already in this question!

Comment: Sorry, I am new in tis awesome Web (and sory for my English, I live in Argentina)
I want to know
1. why Siftei Chakhamim write against the Massora and Chazal, that the word is not totally pointed
2. why no commentary tell about this